# Which table magento use to keep grand total before order place in checkout?

Tags: magento, checkout, cart

Want to know,

1. Before submitting the place order from checkout page which table/storage is magento use to keep the  data like grand total, shipping fee etc?
2. If I add an extra value/amount at checkout ->shipping method step with grand total, it will  show at order review step?

Answer (score 1):

Magento's checkout process is advanced. You need to take a look at Mage_Sales_Model_Quote class and all that is related to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the tables

```
sales_flat_quote
sales_flat_quote_address
sales_flat_quote_item_option
sales_flat_quote_payment
sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate 
sales_flat_quote_.....
```

Thanks